# build postgis 2.0.0 failure

Tags: postgresql, postgis, archlinux

I have postgresql `9.3` installed on archlinux.

I am trying to restore database backup (`psql <db_hame> < backup.file`) which uses postgis 2.0 functions, types etc. I tried to install postgis with pacman (`pacman -S postgis`) it successfully installed but it seems that `2.0` and `2.1` versions are incompatible as I have lots of errors complaining about missing functions during database import:

```
ERROR:  could not find function "geography_analyze" in file "/usr/lib/postgresql/postgis-2.1.so"
ERROR:  function public.geography_analyze(internal) does not exist
ERROR:  function geography_analyze(internal) does not exist
ERROR:  could not find function "geometry_analyze_2d" in file "/usr/lib/postgresql/postgis-2.1.so"
ERROR:  function public.geometry_analyze(internal) does not exist
ERROR:  function geometry_analyze(internal) does not exist
ERROR:  type "geometry" is only a shell
ERROR:  type "public.geometry_dump" does not exist
ERROR:  type "geometry" is only a shell
ERROR:  type "public.valid_detail" does not exist
ERROR:  SQL function cannot accept shell type geography
ERROR:  function public._st_bestsrid(geography) does not exist
ERROR:  PL/pgSQL functions cannot return type geometry
ERROR:  function public._st_concavehull(geometry) does not exist
ERROR:  type "geometry_dump" does not exist
ERROR:  function public._st_dumppoints(geometry, integer[]) does not exist
ERROR:  SQL function cannot accept shell type geometry
ERROR:  function public._st_within(geometry, geometry) does not exist
ERROR:  could not find function "geography_gist_selectivity" in file "/usr/lib/postgresql/postgis-2.1.so"
ERROR:  function public.geography_gist_join_selectivity(internal, oid, internal, smallint) does not exist
ERROR:  could not find function "geography_gist_selectivity" in file "/usr/lib/postgresql/postgis-2.1.so"
ERROR:  function public.geography_gist_selectivity(internal, oid, internal, integer) does not exist
ERROR:  could not find function "geometry_gist_joinsel_2d" in file "/usr/lib/postgresql/postgis-2.1.so"
ERROR:  function public.geometry_gist_joinsel_2d(internal, oid, internal, smallint) does not exist
ERROR:  could not find function "geometry_gist_sel_2d" in file "/usr/lib/postgresql/postgis-2.1.so"
ERROR:  function public.geometry_gist_sel_2d(internal, oid, internal, integer) does not exist
```

Then I tried to build postgis package using following links: http://boringnerdystuff.wordpress.com/2012/04/14/postgis-2-0-pkgbuild-for-arch-linux/ and https://github.com/philbns/PostGIS-2.0-PKGBUILD/tree/80d8af061fa73e9a09dd6ec5c204bc4b65e38202. However build fails with following error:

```
lwgeom_triggers.c: In function ‘cache_bbox’:
lwgeom_triggers.c:78:33: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
  tupdesc = trigdata->tg_relation->rd_att;
```

And whole `makepkg` log: http://pastebin.com/GGqECymZ

How can I import database that uses postgis 2.0 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Huh, that was quite challenging to get it working.

I could not build postgis 2.0.0 against postgres 9.3, so I had to rollback to postgres 9.1.10 and build both postgress and postgis from source.

I used instructions to build postgis from http://boringnerdystuff.wordpress.com/2012/04/14/postgis-2-0-pkgbuild-for-arch-linux/ (itself package is on github: https://github.com/philbns/PostGIS-2.0-PKGBUILD).

Another problem was with postgres package. I tried 9.1.4, but it failed db initialization with some error. Finally I found 9.1.10 that could initialize db. There is no package for postgres 9.1.10, so I used package for postgres 9.1.4 (from https://projects.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/commit/trunk?h=packages/postgresql&id=5bd2e474704f619449287efc7310acebcaf15ab4) then changed `pkgver` to 9.1.10 crossed fingers and hoped everything to be ok. And that worked! I built postgres then postgis and installed them both.

I enabled postgis extension in my db with:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology;
CREATE EXTENSION fuzzystrmatch;
```

And finally my db backup imported without any error.